# install local docker registry on centos 7

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am trying to install a local docker.io registry on a CentOS 7
machine following the instructions here:

https://github.com/docker/docker-registry#quick-start

I ran (EDITED, just to show docker is running):

```
# service docker restart && cd && docker run -p 5000:5000 registry
```

After a few minutes looking at the prompt, I got a bunch of errors like this:

```
[...]
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './registry._setup_database.lock'
[2015-03-06 16:39:11 +0000] [13] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13)
[2015-03-06 16:39:11 +0000] [14] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 14)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 185, in run
    super(Application, self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 71, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 196, in run
    self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 292, in halt
    self.stop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 343, in stop
    time.sleep(0.1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

EDITED:

Details of the system:

```
docker --version
Docker version 1.3.2, build 39fa2fa/1.3.2
```

System:

```
cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)

uname -a
Linux denis1 3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 29 18:05:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Where should this file be? `'./registry._setup_database.lock'`

EDITED2:

If I try it on my Ubuntu 14.10 laptop, where I installed a new version of docker via a ppa, then it works:

```
# Upgraded to docker 1.5 via a ppa package in my Ubuntu laptop:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docker-maint/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker.io

# pull registry latest
sudo docker pull registry:latest

latest: Pulling from registry

fa4fd76b09ce: Downloading 6.931 MB/197.2 MB 3m10s
1c8294cc5160: Download complete 
117ee323aaa9: Download complete 
fa4fd76b09ce: Pull complete 
fa4fd76b09ce: Download complete 
1c8294cc5160: Download complete 
117ee323aaa9: Download complete 
2d24f826cb16: Download complete 
777c3edddace: Download complete 
f06997673ad7: Download complete 
7eafad9a1f16: Download complete 
daa8104aee86: Download complete 
418dcd975ba2: Download complete 
30bff528d188: Download complete 
a4f468439f7f: Download complete 
e5a8e33139de: Download complete 
024a18254446: Download complete 
a68f5599e08a: Download complete 
511136ea3c5a: Download complete 
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry:latest
```

Any ideas what should I do to get the same result on my CentOS server?
Is there a more recent docker client I can get for CentOS 6 via `yum install`?

Comment: What version of docker are you using?  On what platform (ubuntu/rhel/coreos/etc)?

Comment: Stock docker on centos 6

Comment: Run `docker --version` to get the version of Docker.

Comment: `docker version 1.3.2` is the one that gets installed on the CentOS system.

Comment: Double-check that you haven't done something like built your own image named 'registry'? Explicitly pull `registry:latest`? I don't see anything you're doing wrong. I feel suspicious that the `registry` image might just be broken for RedHat family with Docker 1.3.

Comment: pull registry:latest gives me a not found

Comment: OK, that's interesting. You've definitely got something wrong on your side, because `docker pull registry:latest` does work.

Comment: Indeed `sudo docker pull registry:latest` works on my laptop with docker version `1.5.0-dev, build a78ce5c`, but still no luck with the CentOS server. Updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable SELINUX and FireWalld.

SELINUX is preventing execution of certain commands as SUDO which is somehow inhibiting behavior.

Also check FireWallD as well.

Neither of upgrade of docker version or "latest" tag etc will solve your problem, I tried them all... it has to do with SELINUX and/or FireWallD... disable both if you can.

I upgraded docker version to 1.5.0 by adding this to yum.repos.d:

```
[virt7-testing]
name=virt7-testing
baseurl=http://cbs.centos.org/repos/virt7-testing/x86_64/os/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like we can summarize things like this:

The [documentation for 'registry'](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/registry/) says it only supports docker 1.5. You're running 1.3 and there's a pretty big jump between these.

> ### Supported Docker versions
>
> This image is officially supported on Docker version 1.5.0.
>
> Support for older versions (down to 1.0) is provided on a best-effort
>   basis.

On CentOS 6.5, you can `yum install docker` from EPEL ([Docker instructions](https://docs.docker.com/installation/centos/#installing-docker---centos-6.5)) and get Docker 1.5. Earlier than 6.5, you must `yum install docker-io` and it appears that 1.4 is the latest available version from EPEL.

In my experience, Docker's support on RedHat-family systems has been poorer then on Debian-family, but this gap has closed in the most recent versions of RH and Docker.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense now. I have updated my question for centos 7. It turns out it was centos 7 all along, only there is still no way to make it work for the default docker.io, which is 1.3.2.