# How to install the latest version of Docker on CentOS 7

Tags: docker, centos7

I am trying to have a modern docker.io version 1.5+ installed on a CentOS 7 64bit system.

The default docker.io that comes with the yum servers is 1.3.2, and
this version is too old for some of the docker.io features I need, e.g.

([install local docker registry on centos 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28904121/719016))

Details of the system:

```
docker --version
Docker version 1.3.2, build 39fa2fa/1.3.2
```

System:

```
cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)

uname -a
Linux hostname 3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 29 18:05:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any ideas how to install a modern docker.io 1.5+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did:

1. Add a repo to yum using this command

`sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/cbs.repo`

and with this contents:

```
[virt7-testing]
name=virt7-testing
baseurl=http://cbs.centos.org/repos/virt7-testing/x86_64/os/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

2. Start yum using `Applications -> System Tools -> Software`
3. Search for `Docker`
4. Note that docker 1.5.x is available for install.
5. If Docker 1.3.2 is installed, uninstall it by unchecking it and clicking apply.
6. Click the check box next to Docker 1.5.x and click apply.
7. Test that the install was successful by running `docker --version` from command line.

Comment: virt7-testing is good.  
  
The repo definition in yum.repos.d needs a .repo extension for yum to be detected.  

`sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/cbs.repo`  

  
After this change a `yum update` replaced the installed docker 1.3.2 with docker 1.5.0

Answer (score 5):

Please see the [official user guide on installing the latest version of Docker on CentOS](https://docs.docker.com/installation/centos/#manual-installation-of-latest-docker-release)

At the very start it says: "*While using a package is the recommended way of installing Docker, the above package might not be the current release version. If you need the latest version, you can install the binary directly.*"

This tells you how to do that: https://docs.docker.com/installation/binaries/

Basically:

- check your dependencies
- download the binary: `wget https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest -O docker`
- run the daemon: `sudo ./docker -d &`

Now you're good to go.

Comment: The official guide only makes you install the version available in the official CentOS 7 repos, which is 1.3.2 unfortunately.

Comment: At the very start it says: "_While using a package is the recommended way of installing Docker, the above package might not be the current release version. If you need the latest version, you can install the binary directly._". This tells you how to do that: https://docs.docker.com/installation/binaries/ Basically: check your dependencies, download the binary from `wget https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest -O docker` then run the daemon: `sudo ./docker -d &` Now you're good to go.

Comment: I had somehow missed that, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Page has moved: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/